# How can I edit a website's content in the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

I heard, I can't remember where, someone talking about editing a website's content directly in the url, like an argument that allows you to type HTML and/or CSS code in the url. I'm asking you here what is the name, if it exists, of this kind of editing, as I can't find anything related to this online.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: That would be a major security flaw. Maybe you're getting confused with queryString parameters or developer tools

Comment: @mplungjan - I think it's easy to "translate" this question into "Is there a technology that allows me to edit websites by modifying parts of their URL? If so, what's the name?" I think that's a valid and clear question. (While yes, the wording could be optimized.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to craft a URL which will cause the browser to navigate to an arbitrary existing page but modify it before presenting it to the user.

Some websites are designed so that information can be encoded into the query string (e.g. search engines support https://duckduckgo.com/?q=example+search).

Some websites have [XSS vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).